# Where did Itsuwa`s sweater go? (Continuity issue)

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

This question contains potential spoilers for episode 8 of Index 3!

In Episode 8 of Toaru Majutsu no Index III during the battle between the

> Amakusa church members and Aqua of the Rear in the scene where Itsuwa attacks Aqua with the Saint Destroyer we have the following scenes:
>  In the first scene Itsuwa is wearing her turtle neck sweater [image: Itsuwa strike Aqua] and she is still wearing it when Aqua strikes her and throws her through the ceiling. [image: Itsuwa falls through the ceiling] However the moment they show her on the ground the sweater is suddenly gone [image: Magically disappearing sweater] During the remaining scenes the sweater remains missing. From the shots it is obvious that Itsuwa did not have the strength nor the means to remove the sweater herself. So now my question is, is this a continuity error in the show or did the sweater disappear in some other way?

Comment: Probably got blown off with the attack because that's how logic in anime works. That's just weird the sweater has been worn under the crop top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's glossed over in the anime, but in the novels, she was using a spell that diverted damage onto her clothes. When they took that attack, it was enough to burn up the sweater.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange! This looks like a good starting point for a good answer. To make it better, could you also mention the name of the novel, the volume no. & chapter no./title, and the quote/surrounding passage describing this? You can always [edit] your post to improve it :)